# Review form is not being submitted

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

In my project, I added a new field `location` in "product reviews" of admin panel going through the following steps as explained in many blogs.

- Created a new field in database table `review_detail` as `location`.
- Added the following code in `app/code/code/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php`

  ```
      $fieldset->addField('location', 'text', array(
              'name'  => 'location',
              'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Location'),
              'required' => false
          )
      );
  ```

Just above:

```
    $fieldset->addField('nickname', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'nickname'
    ));
```

- .Added the following code in `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review.php`

  ```
  $detail = array(
      'title'     => $object->getTitle(),
      'detail'    => $object->getDetail(),
      'nickname'  => $object->getNickname(),
      'location'  => $object->getLocation()   /* added */
  );
  ```
- Added "*location*" in below function array. In the file: `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review/Collection.php`

  ```
  protected function _initSelect()
  {
      parent::_initSelect();
      $this->getSelect()
          ->join(array('detail' => $this->_reviewDetailTable),
              'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id',
              array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id','location'));
      return $this;
  }
  ```
- Added the following in `{$mytheme}/template/review/form.phtml`:

  ```
  <li>
        <label for="location_field" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Location') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
             <input type="text" name="nickname" id="location_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($data->getLocation()) ?>" />
        </div>
  </li>
  ```

**My problem is that though I can see a new field in admin panel, whenever I submit a review form it is not being submitted/stored in database.**

I even re-indexed and cleared the cache.

What should I change more to make it work properly?

Please help... I am on magento 1.8.

PS: I know core files should not be changed. I will override this to new module once I have success in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did follow exact steps explained in quetion. And find it working properly.

Only issue I faced was that in `{$mytheme}/template/review/form.phtml`

You have defined `name="nickname"` for location field instead of `name="location"`

Correct this and if you still face same issue than then check if Module Classes as being overridden.

Comment: I never thought this.. setting the `name` to "location" solved the issue. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the html code created in the browser. Check for:

- is your field included within -tags?
- is the action type and target set correctly?
- with a browser console of your choice (e.g. chrome F12) ensure that fields are correctly set and the form is really sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  take db backup first.  Delete entry of table from core_resource table and load the site.. In short try to recreate the db table with your column 'location'. I don't know ,what is wrong with setters when we add new field in varien forms they didn't work properly.

I hope this will work.